# UIFileSharingEnabled on debug variant only

Tags: ios, xcode

I am looking for a way to enable the UIFileSharingEnabled flag for only a debug variant - so I can change the contents of the documents folder - but I don't want end users to be doing the same.

I guess i could use a run script to do it, though not sure how to get the active configuration name to the script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

worked it out:

```
if [ ${CONFIGURATION} = "Debug" ]; then
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :UIFileSharingEnabled YES" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"
else
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :UIFileSharingEnabled NO" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"
fi
```

Comment: Good! One additional note-- for a new project, you may need to add UIFileSharingEnabled into your Info.plist. With Xcode 7, I had to do this.

Comment: Perfect answer!