# Delphi XE2 File Sharing and iOS

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I need to set UIFileSharingEnabled to yes in the .plist file in my FireMonkey application.  This can be done manually in Xcode (and works), however each time I modify the code in Delphi and use the "Export to Xcode" menu item the .plist file is recreated and changes I have made are lost.

Is there a setting or mechanism in XE2 to have UIFileSharingEnabled or other settings added to the project .plist file whenever it is created?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing it in Delphi you can change it in xcode by running a script, here's example: [UIFileSharingEnabled on debug variant only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276390/uifilesharingenabled-on-debug-variant-only)

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't directly answer your question, be aware that it seems that you only need to export to xcode as a 'one off'.  I.e.  each time you make a change you do not need to re-export.

An exception seems to be if you add additional units to your application.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I didn't realize that.  However I get the message "No code signature found" when Xcode builds the project.  This message doesn't happen if I have done the "Export to Xcode" in Delphi.  Something else is happening in the project code that dprtoxcode is doing....

Comment: I am using a shared folder on the pc, and then compiling on the mac from that shared (pc) folder.  Perhaps it has something to do with the setup?  Another workaround you could try (not at work now so I can't try it)
 
* set the plist file to readonly, though in all likelyhood you may get an export error doing this.

* set up a batch file (or quick and dirty delphi program) to copy the a saved plist file over the top, and configure it as a tool in the delphi ide under the 'export to xcode' so you can perform the two operations together.