# Set info Plist Bool Programmatically

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xcode6

Can I change the infoPlist Bool for `Application supports iTunes file sharing` programmatically

Something along the lines of:

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"Application_supports_iTunes_file_sharing"] = NO]];`

Comment: mainBundle is a read-only, that's why the info.plist can't be modified during runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, for the same reason that [you cannot change values inside `plist.info` programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12817272/335858).

If you need a changeable data element for your own app, it goes to `NSUserDefaults`. All the special flags in `info.plst` need to be set statically. [You can have different flags based on compilation target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4276390/335858) (say, debug vs. release), but it needs to be compiled into your bundle statically.